# GDI+ Only Draw Screen Correctly the First Time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, gdi+

I am coding a checkers game. I have a CBoard class which has 2 vectors of pointers to `CGamePieces` and `CTiles`. The first time the board is drawn, it draws perfectly. If I try to make any modifications to the vectors and draw again, the original board is redrawn without the changes being reflected.

Here's how I add elements to those vectors:

```
void CBoard::getPieces()
{
    while(mGamePieces.size() < 12)
    {
        shared_ptr<CWhitePiece> white(new CWhitePiece());
        white->setBoard(this);
        white->setTile(mTiles[tileIndex]);
        mGamePieces.push_back(white);
    }
}
```

To draw the board, I call a Draw function on all of the `CTiles` and `CGamePieces` by iterating over the vectors, which look like this:

```
void CGamePiece::Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics * graphics)
{
    double wid = 100;
    double hit = 100;
    graphics->DrawImage(mImage.get(),
        float(mTile->getColumn() / 2) + 100 * mTile->getColumn(), float(mTile->getRow() / 2) + 100 * mTile->getRow(),
        100.0, 100.0);
}
```

Using the debugger, I see that the vector that's being iterated over has the changes reflected - if I delete something there is one less item and if I add something, that item is present in the vector. This code is being called just before the board is redrawn:

```
void CBoard::move()
{
    shared_ptr<CBrownPiece> brown(new CBrownPiece());
    brown->setBoard(this);
    brown->setTile(mTiles[30]);
    mGamePieces.push_back(brown);
}
```

Since the changes seem to be made to the vector when debugging, I'm not sure why this additional piece wouldn't be drawn on the screen, especially when I can see the Draw function being called on it. If the board is drawn by calling draw on each item of these vectors, shouldn't items being added/removed to the vector be drawn/removed from the screen?

I redraw the screen when a piece is clicked

```
/** 
 * When the mouse is pressed down, we will run the HitTest function.
 * If HitTest does not return a nullpointer, we will run the 
 * move function.
 */
void CChildView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // Check if a piece has been clicked
    mClickedPiece = mBoard.HitTest(point.x, point.y);

    if (mClickedPiece != nullptr && !mClickedPiece->getClicked())
    {
        mClickedPiece->setClicked(true); // This will allow us to find the piece to move in the vector of CGamePieces
        mBoard.move();
        OnPaint();
        //mClickedPiece->setClicked(false);
    }
}

/** This function is called to draw in the window.
*
* This function is called in response to a drawing message
* whenever we need to redraw the window on the screen.
* It is responsible for painting the window.
*/
void CChildView::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC paintDC(this);     // device context for painting
    CDoubleBufferDC dc(&paintDC); // device context for painting
    Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC);
    mBoard.OnDraw(&graphics);
}
```

Comment: mGamePieces is a member variable of CBoard, and is of type vector<shared_ptr<CGamePiece>>, where CGamePiece is the base class for CBrownPiece. I'm actually unsure why this would fail?

Comment: Are you drawing (only) in response to a WM_PAINT message?

Comment: After the first draw, I'm drawing in response to the screen being clicked. I just edited to post to include that code.

Comment: Quote: "A CPaintDC object can only be used when responding to a WM_PAINT message".  So you can't call OnPaint() directly like you do, force a repaint by calling CWnd::Invalidate().

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton. That worked. One thing - it seems to react very slowly. Is there any way I can fix this?